# check if a part of the file name from folderone matches in a folder two and output both if a match found

Tags: powershell

check if a part of the file name in folderone matches with a part of a file name in foldertwo.
  forex: `april_logs-0410.txt` in folderone matches with `april_logs-0310.txt` in foldertwo.
  I need to see the matched full file name in foldertwo..ex april_logs-0310.txt must be printed in the output.

```
$folderone = Get-ChildItem -Recurse folderone
foreach($file in $folderone)
{
$fileNon = $file.Name -split'(?=-\d)' #splits the filename with -0410
$newfile = $fileNon[0] #this has april_logs
If (test-path "d:\foldertwo\$newfile" -pathtype leaf)) {
write-host "$newfile is in foldertwo"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a given tree:

```
> tree a:\ /f
A:\
├───Folder1
│       april_logs-0410.txt
│       may_logs-0510.txt
│
└───Folder2
        april_logs-0310.txt
```

this one line

```
gci Folder1\*-[0-9]*|? Name -match '^(.*)-\d'|%{(gci Folder2\$($matches[1])*).FullName}
```

yields:

```
A:\Folder2\april_logs-0310.txt
```

This more verbose and slightly different script:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\10\SO_55605777.ps1
$FolderOne = 'A:\Folder1'
$FolderTwo = 'A:\Folder2'
foreach($File in (
    Get-ChildItem $FolderOne\*-[0-9]* |
    Where-Object Name -match '^(.*)-\d'|
    Select-Object FullName,@{n='Pattern';e={$Matches[1]}} )){
    if($Found = (Get-ChildItem $FolderTwo\$($File.Pattern)*).FullName){
        "{0} is matched by:" -f $File.FullName
         $Found
    }
}
```

yields:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\04\10\SO_55605777.ps1
A:\Folder1\april_logs-0410.txt is matched by:
A:\Folder2\april_logs-0310.txt
```

Comment: if there is a another file march_logs-124.txt in foldertwo , irrespective of match its printing "A:\Folder1\march_logs-124.txt is matched by:" . try to figure out a way to restrict it to print the matched by line only if a file is matched . @LotPings

Comment: added this before "{0} i matched: 'If (test-path "$FolderTwo\$newfile-*" -pathtype leaf) {'

Comment: See changed script and sample tree.